# Can OpenERP display a grid view based on the selection in a dropdown list?

Tags: python, odoo

In .NET, when the user selects a value from a dropdown list, you can make it reload different data in a grid view according to which value was selected in the dropdown list.

Can I do the same thing in OpenERP? When the user selects a value from a many2one field, can I automatically display a grid of data?

Comment: I tried to clarify your question, Santu. Did I understand it correctly? It would be really helpful if you gave an example here. Maybe describe what the choices might be in the drop down and what you would like to see in the grid for each choice. A sketch of the screen design would also make it easier to understand.

Comment: It could be possible if your record saved before executing on_change on M2O field.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any screens like that, but you might be able to do something like it. The [`on_change` event](http://doc.openerp.com/v5.0/developer/2_6_views_events/events/events.html#on-change-event-link) of fields can trigger changes in other fields on the screen. You can definitely use that to change simple fields, but I don't know if you could use it to populate a grid of data. The documentation says you can change the domain of some fields, so that might be what you want: just add a filter to a child table.